# How can I get list of rooms user joined via another model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have 3 models: User, Room, Join. I'm trying to get a list of room user has joined but I don't know how.

```
# models.py
class User(models.Model):
  full_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class Room(models.Model):
  room_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
  create_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Join(models.Model):
  room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I tried using related_name and related_query_name but unfortunately I don't know how these things work. If my question is duplicated, please provide me some keywords, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain the `Room`s for which a `Join` with *`myuser`* exists with:

```
Room.objects.filter(join__user=myuser)
```

If it is possible that the same `User` has joined the same `Room` multiple times, you can work with:

```
Room.objects.filter(join__user=myuser).distinct()
```

Comment: Can i have the link the documentation about that "join__user"? Thank you very much!

Comment: @HaloNewWorld: see the [*making queries*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/) that explains step-by-step how to define queries.